# Permission Denied on Exec() w/ -rwxr-xr-x

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, laravel, cmd

**I have tried permissions but still getting this error

```
Array ( [0] => sh: 1: /var/www/nodejs/tmp: Permission denied )
```

The command is execute from the route file of Laravel(MVC PHP Web application)

Tried CHMOD 777 , CHMOD +x etc.

My current permission is as follows

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root *number* Oct 9 21:35 test.js
```

What did i not do?

My php code

```
$user_input = "http://google.com/";

    putenv("PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE=/usr/local/bin/phantomjs");
    exec('/var/www/nodejs/tmp test.js $user_input 2>&1',$output);

    print_r($output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your test.js may be a script

In that case make sure the interpreter is also executable

another possibility is that your file is on a filesystem with no execute permissions

Comment: The interpreter , which i believe is the file i send the command out from is a php file. Did a +x to it , same issue. What do you mean by file is no a filesystem with no execute permissions? The folder & it's file can be executed.

Answer (score 0):

If `test.js` resides in directory `/var/www/nodejs/tmp`, they are not to be separated by space, but joined by slash:

```
    exec('/var/www/nodejs/tmp/test.js $user_input 2>&1', $output);
```